# Determining the active control within an application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on an application which has multiple forms and dialogs. Part of the functionality are a set of cut, copy and paste buttons on a ribbon. So far I have not been able to write code which handles the cut copy and paste operations. My problem is as follows:

In the Application.Idle event of my main form, I'm trying to figure out the currently active control, regardless of the currently active form (which could be the main form, an mdi child or a dialog. After a lot of trial and error, this is my most successful attempt:

```
Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm;
Control activeControl = activeForm.ActiveControl;
```

This works well for most of the situations, but when a control is embedded in a container (for instance a floating dockpanel), the activeControl variable returns the container control, and not the textbox on it which has the focus.

Am I missing something here? Is there perhaps a better way of implementing this functionality?

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this on a form with a `GroupBox` containing a couple of controls and it worked as expected (but for production code you should probably add some null-checks in case nothing is selected, or the app doesn't have focus at all):

```
Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm;
Control activeControl = activeForm.ActiveControl;
while (activeControl.HasChildren)
{
    activeControl = activeControl
        .Controls
        .Cast<Control>()
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Focused);
}
```

On the other hand, if you are using a third party docking library (you mentioned a DockPanel, so I am thinking of [Weifen Luo's DockPanel Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/), for example), then you will have to use their own properties (e.g. `DockPanel.ActiveDocument` or `DockPanel.ActiveContent`) to get the docked form, but the general idea stays the same.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks for your prompt reply!

Comment: With some slight modifications, it works like a charm! Thanks again.